Error al levantar contenedor en Hadoop. Queda reiniciando constantemente
Me encuentro trabajando en una maquina virtual.
Anteriormente habia levantado un docker-compose sin problema. Ahora, el estado de un contenedor específico, queda constantemente en "restarting" y otros 2 en "unhealthy".
Al ejecutar el comando "sudo docker logs <...>" en referencia al contenedor que se encuentra "restarting", me indica que hay un error para cargar una imagen desde el sistema de archivos (FSImage) desde un archivo específico.
Probé deteniendo, eliminando y volviendo a levantarlos pero el problema persiste.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! borraste la cache de imagenes tambien?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
